# Action of $ \mathbb{G}_m $ on $ \mathbb{A}^n $ by multiplication.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Consider the action of $ \mathbb{G}_m $ on $ \mathbb{A}^n $ by scalar multiplication : $ t.(a_1 , \dots , a_n ) = ( ta_1 , \dots , ta_n ) $.

In this case, there are two types of orbits :

- punctured lines through the origin.
- the origin.

Please, why does every orbit contain the origin in its closure ? and why is the origin a closed orbit ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Because what is the closure of a punctured line through the origin ? Also, the origin is closed because it is a closed point... I don't know what is troubling you here...

Comment: From topology point of view the closure of a punctured line through the origin is all the line through the origin, but from algebraic geometry point of view, i don't know how to reason and relatively to which kind of topology ?

Comment: I guess the topology is Zariski, but that the origin is closed and that the closure of a punctured line is the whole line is exactly the same as in usual topology.

Comment: Thank you Roland.  :-)